# Encrypt geometry data in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a column with geometry data in postgres DB with postGIS enabled.Please help me with a way to encrypt/decrypt that column.

postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-geometric.html - the column that i have can contain any of the geometry types. I need a way to encrypt the data while writing to the DB and way to decrypt it while reading the same data back

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to give us more details, and the overall context could help. As such, I'm afraid your question cannot be answered.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-geometric.html - the column that i have can contain any of the geometry types. I need a way to encrypt the data while writing to the DB and way to decrypt it while reading the same data back.

Comment: No no, I meant by editing the question (clic on "edit"), adding details in comments is not the correct way, the question must be fully understandable without the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

**PostgreSQL encryption**

This can be done on many levels:

- Encryption For Specific Columns
- Data Partition Encryption
- Encrypting Data Across A Network
- etc.

[Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/encryption-options.html)

**Application-level encryption**

Encryption:

- application: has geometric data into intermediary format (e.g. JSON)
- application: encrypts intermediary format into binary data
- application: persists binary data to database

Decryption:

- application: reads binary data from database
- application: decrypts binary data into intermediary format
- application: now has usable geometric data